# How to two apps from django to conect one db postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have a little question.

I have an app in Django rest framework with PostgreSQL(the project called djangoFall), and I build other projects with Django called djangoRuim, but I don't know how to connect and read the tables in the djangoRuim for example

djangoFall connect with the PostgreSQL is working

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'colonybitdb0',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'root2017',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
} }
```

in here I can read tables like this

```
from djangoFall.profile_clbt.models import HelperNotificationMsg
```

djangoRuim connect with the same connect PostgreSQL DB is working but I don't how to read the tables

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'colonybitdb0',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'root2017',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
}}
```

in here I can't read the same table

```
from .models import HelperNotificationMsg # wrong true ?
```

because here I don't have models.

please help me, how to read these tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `connection` object to [execute direct SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) to the table's name generated by Django in the second app or the value you assigned to `db_table` in the `Meta` option in the second app `models.py`. This will work here because you are using the same database settings for the two apps.

In case of different database settings, you will need to explicitly connect to the external database with the driver and execute the SQL query.

That being said, since you are using the same database, I think you should consider merging those two apps, or package one. But it depends on what you're trying to archive and the overall architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really mandatory to access to the very same database from two different django applications, here is what needs to be done:

1. Create the same object model in both applications, make sure each object member are identical.
2. Use the same credentials and url to access the database.
3. Now, both of these applications can access to the database with implicit race condition protection, presuming that the database has native support for that. (All modern databases have that support.)